# After implementing .htaccess my sites load twice, why?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

After implementing an .htaccess-file in order to make the single pages of my website accessible with simple */folder/* links, certain (if not all) pages load twice.

I noticed this when a counter that counts the number of clicks a certain content on my site gets, incremented twice, whenever I visited the page.

This only happened after I created the .htaccess-file.

Is this a common problem or am I the only one experiencing this? What is there to be done in order to prevent this?

Besides some rewrite conditions, there's nothing in my .htaccess-file ...

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on

#remove PHPSESSID 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$ 
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

#content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?(content)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ index.php?nav=single&ID=$2 [QSA,L]

#comments
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?(comments)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?nav=comments&ID=$2&catID=$3 [QSA,L]

#normal pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?nav=$1 [QSA,L]


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Might want to show the relevant parts of your htaccess file

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file

Comment: @John Conde I'm sorry, totally forgot this part! See above! I have no idea why I'm doing the compress-thing. I wrote this some time ago ...

Comment: Check your web server logs. Are the pages actually being served twice or do you maybe have a bug in your counting code?

Comment: Do you have example paths that seem to load twice?

Comment: This is being caused by some external resource on your page - an image, script, css file etc - that is also falling through this .htaccess and being rewritten to run through `index.php`, thereby incrementing the counter. Look at all the HTML elements that have a `href` or `src` attribute - one of those will be the culprit. There is also a possibility that it's `favicon.ico` that is causing this, although that doesn't appear to match any of your rewrite rules.

Comment: Funny how this question is closed for not being a "real question", yet has a real answer that solves the problem presented by the OP.

Comment: mhmm, asked myself the same question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter is incremented before the redirect, could be a variety of reasons. One reason is using absolute paths for external resources. They will be rewritten too, and potentially cause problems.

Here's an idea:

add this in between the < head> tags of the template:

```
<base href="/">
```

If that doesn't work, try moving the counter function to the very last few lines before the output buffer would be cleared.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for this easy answer!

Could you, if possible, shortly explain why this does indeed work?

Comment: Server: "Okay, redirect complete. Begin script and increment counter. Oh. Wait a minute- redirect this resource link, too. Begin script and increment counter."

Comment: I'm a big fan of one-liners, too- especially the server-side-language agnostic ones:)

Comment: could you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895224/make-htaccess-rule-apply-only-to-the-current-folder/ ?