# Mod Rewrite loads page twice

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with my Mod Rewrite in my `.htaccess` file.

I currently have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which causes the page to load twice causing a function I'm calling on that page to be called twice.

Does anyone know a fix for this issue? Have been looking around on Google but couldn't find any concrete answers.

Comment: I don't see how it can be caused by those directives? What URL are you requesting? Does _every_ page load twice? And by "load twice", do you mean there are two HTTP requests for the same URL?

Comment: @w3dk I'm requesting support/ticket/3 and it only happens on pages with three vars in the url

Comment: @w3dk By "load twice" I mean that the page is requested twice. Like I said in the post, I have a function on that page which is called when the page is requested. I've tested the amount of times it's called by using `file_put_contents`. It shows that the page is "loaded" twice. When removing the Mod Rewrite, the page "loads" once

Comment: There must be _something else_ going on here, the code you posted above will not cause this. The redirect would seem to be caused by your "web application". All the code does above is _internally rewrite_ the request to `index.php` (which would seem to be essential for the URL to be routed). `index.php` then processes the request. If you remove those directives then yes, it may stop the redirection, because it stops your application from working. (?)

Comment: Are there any other directives? Any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Is `/support` or `/support/ticket` physical directories? Do you have any other canonical redirect (eg. non-www to www, HTTP to HTTPS)?

Comment: @w3dk Well, the thing is if you look at the output of `file_put_contents` it actually shows one output when not using `.htaccess` and two when using it. So the application still works, with some adjustments, but for some reason the `.htaccess` has something to do with this.

Comment: You say you are requesting `example.com/support/ticket/3`. What is the name of the file that contains the `file_put_contents()` call?

Comment: @w3dk It's called `im_called`. It's in a `tmp` directory.

Comment: So how is `/tmp/im_called` being called? How does the request get from `/support/ticket/3` to `/tmp/im_called`?

Comment: I have a function which is called from `/support/ticket/3` which executes `file_put_contents('C://xampp/htdocs/tmp/im_called', time() . '(' . $loc . ')' . "\n", FILE_APPEND);` where `$loc` is a string which contains the page name.

Comment: "called from `/support/ticket/3`" - is `/support/ticket/3` a physical file?!

Comment: @w3dk Haha that's not what I meant. I mean the page which is shown by going to `/support/ticket/3`. The page contains a function.

Comment: So, how is the request routed when you request `/support/ticket/3`? When you remove the `.htaccess`, a request for `/support/ticket/3` is still successfully routed??

Comment: @w3dk Starts at `index.php` which contains a switch that checks the first part of the url (support) and requests a file called `support-page.php` which also contains a switch and again checks the url but this time for the second part of the url (ticket) and then requests a file called `support_ticket.php` which checks the last part of the url (3) and loads the view.

Comment: @w3dk And no, if I remove the `.htaccess` file the request is not routed anymore. I checked it before by changing the check for the url to a simple `$_GET` and by calling `/support-page.php?ID=support_ticket` which then showed the page as usual but this time the output of `file_put_contents` was only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using the following:

```
<base href="/">
```

Found here: [After implementing .htaccess my sites load twice, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956210/after-implementing-htaccess-my-sites-load-twice-why)